# Cucumber execution with maven

Tags: maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

I am using the below maven project to try out the cucumber example.

http://artoftesting.com/automationTesting/sampleScript/cucumberJava.zip

The compilation works fine but the test fails with the below error..

```
Results :

Tests in error: 
initializationError(artOfTesting.googleCalcTest): Failed to instantiate     public cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend(cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader) with [cucumber.runtime.io.MultiLoader@59fa1d9b]

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

Below is the snapshot of my pom.xml.

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>CucumberJavaProject</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumberJava</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.47.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId> 
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId> 
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


     <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>


 </dependencies>  
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                <threadCount>20</threadCount>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Do i need to include any other jars apart from these to overcome this error ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the `cucumber-java` dependency version matches the `cucumber-core` one.  Replace:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

with:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Do i need to re-version my maven surefire plugin as well..as my build fails with the below errorm

Comment: org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: @user2189668 What is the full stacktrace?  It's more likely that you're missing another dependency.

Comment: org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)

Comment: This is the stack trace.

Comment: It works fine now.. I have upgraded the maven surefire to the latest...thanks much.

Comment: @user2189668 glad to hear it!